# Overriding toString() in Exception Handling

Tags: java, tostring, overriding

```
public class ExcepHand  {
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Exception Occured";
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a=10;
        int b=0;
        try
        {
            int c=a/b;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an output `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`. I would like to know why the `toString()` method is not overridden. If it is possible to do so, pls tell me how to do it.

Comment: Because at no point in your code is toString being called on an instance of ExcepHand.

Comment: `toString()` is not called when an exception is catched. To call `toString()` in this case you'd have to create an instance of `ExcepHand` like `ExcepHand obj = new ExcepHand()` and then call `obj.toString()`

Comment: I would strongly recommend working through an organized Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the `toString()` of your `ExcepHand` class and not the `toString()` of the `java.lang.ArithmeticException` class.

If you want to write another log-message you could simply write a string if you catched an ArithmeticException.

Some ideas of Exceptionhandling:

You catch an Exception, if you simple log the message,you will lose the line and class inforamation. You should prefert to call `printStacktrace()`.

Later you should start looking at logging-frameworks, like `log4j` or `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the `toString()` method for `ExcepHand` instances. You're Exception is an instance of `ArithmeticException` which has nothing to do with your class.

To call you own `toString()` method, change your code to create a new instance of `ExcepHand`:

```
catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println(new ExcepHand()); // prints "Exception Occured"
    System.out.println(e); // prints "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"
}
```

You could also extend the `ArithmeticException` to wrap your own message around the original `ArithmeticException` message:

```
public class ExcepHand extends ArithmeticException {
    private static final String messageTemplate = "Exception Occured: %s";

    public ExcepHand() {
        this("");
    }

    public ExcepHand(String s) {
        super(String.format(messageTemplate, s));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 0;
        try {
            int c = a / b;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(new ExcepHand(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
ExcepHand: Exception Occured: / by zero
```

Or use `System.out.println(new ExcepHand(e.toString()));` to get:

```
ExcepHand: Exception Occured: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
try {
    int c=a/b;
}
catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println(new ExcepHand());//it will automatically call toString of you ExceptHand object but an ugly way to do it.
}
```

You are calling toString method of ArithmeticException and not ExcepHand.

Comment: This would call the toString(), but seems to bee really useless, because, he could directy write the line in that case.

Comment: I agree. But for OP's understanding i used such an ugly code.

Comment: You are right, but I thought it is a good dea to mention "This would make your code work, but you should not do it".

Comment: Yea i did mentioned it in my comment in answer "you ExceptHand object but an ugly way to do it."